# TestFlight with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, testflight

I am trying to distribute my ad hoc app to testers through TestFlight and the ASIHTTPRequest library is included in my app. The app will request the server and get the JSON String from it when launch. However it didn't call either success or fail block.

I have read articles on [Github](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/issues/320) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604162/asihttprequest-request-times-out) such that I knew there is a issue between TestFlight and ASIHTTPRequest.

After removing the TestFlight SDK, the problems still exist if distributed by TestFlight's platform but not building directly from Xcode.

Is there any way for me to distribute my app with TestFlight?

My Code for connection:

```
-(void)connectServerWithURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    __weak ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(downloadDataSuccessWithWithRequest:url:)])
        {
            [self.delegate downloadDataSuccessWithWithRequest:request url:url];
        }
    }];
    [request setFailedBlock:^{
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(downloadDataFailureWithRequest:url:)])
        {
            [self.delegate downloadDataFailureWithRequest:request url:url];
        }
    }];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the TestFlight SDK, I've not seen this problem at all. Also be aware that `ASIHTTPRequest` is no longer being supported by it developer and he suggested you move to an other library like [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [`MKNetworkKit`](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit).

Comment: Thanks, I will switch to AFNetworking and see whats going on.

Comment: @rckoenes Its from the ASIHTTPRequest's bug, another [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9583249/837059) explained this. After using AFNetworking it is completely fine. Thanks!